# Trouble combining Data Extension data with List Data in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, data

I'm trying to combine both Data Extension data and List data into AMPscript for inserting content into an email.  At the most basic level, I find someone's browse history from a table that stores daily browse activity, and combine that with a condition that checks to see if a member has a certain status or not (which is list data).

For example:

IF @subject_brand == "some browse category" AND Membership_Number > 0 THEN ...

where @subject_brand is declared earlier in the email, and if the numeric Membership_Number is greater than zero, it means it exists and they are a member.

I've tried combining different brackets, but with no luck.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this, but sometimes it gets a bit quirky.  I'm assuming Membership_Number is an attribute or a field in the sendable DE... sometimes (and I'm not sure when), you need to do something like

SET @membershipNumber = Membership_Number

IF @subject_brand == "some browse category" AND @membershipNumber > 0 THEN ...

Give that a try.